# javascript recursive function callback how to identify when all function calls have ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, data-structures, callback

```
  function transverse(element, result) {
        if (angular.isArray(element)){
            element.forEach(function (item) {
                { transverse(item, result); }
            });
        }

        else if ( angular.isObject(element)) {
            var transform;

            if (element.hasOwnProperty("dataMetrics")) {
                console.log(element);

            }

            if (element.hasOwnProperty("childNodes")) {
                transverse(element.childNodes, result);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I have a function written in javascript that traverses over a json object of tree structure. But i want to add a callback, once that function is over it should call that method.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why is a callback needed? This is all synchronous. You could just add `if (callback) { callback(); }` to the end of the function (and make the function accept an additional argument), but it's not adding any benefit in this case.

Comment: where exactly can i add that block?

Comment: `traverse(...); afterTraverse();` will do that. No need for a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the code you have posted is executed asynchronously, including the `forEach` call.

For this reason, you don't need a callback. Simply continue with the code that should follow after the recursive traversal after the initial call of `transverse`.

Example, demonstrating the synchronous nature of `forEach`:

```js
var input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

input.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});

console.log('done');
```